# Временами не работают горячие клавиши в ubuntu 16.04.2 lts

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Проблема возникает в течении каждого часа и длится примерно 5 минут. Суть проблемы в том что горячие клавиши например ctrl + c, ctrl + z не отвечают на запросы. При этом сам компьютер работает, не виснет. Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS , xenial. Клавиатуру пробовал использовать другую, переставлял в разные порты разные клавиатуры. Итог один и тот же. В языковой расскладке стоит сперва английский язык потом русский. Кто может сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Скорее всего это известный баг, связанный с тем, что хоткей не работает в русской раскладке. Проведете испытания.

Comment: На xfce (manjaro и xubuntu) я никогда не сталкивался ни с чем подобным. Скорее всего баг зависит от ДЕ.

Comment: а мышка при этом кликает по кнопкам или просто ползает никуда не нажимая?

Comment: @eri мышка работает, сами хот кеи не отвечают

Comment: Такое впечатление, что у вас драйвер выпадает в осадок (или сама клавиатура). Остальные-то кнопки работают?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился: все дело в intellij. Это программа распознает горячие клавиши только в английской раскладке. Не замечал что язык переключался на русский. Всем спасибо за мозговой штурм)